# How to mark length on Pixelmator Pro?

Tags: pixelmator

I was wondering if Pixelmator Pro can do some basic ruler & mark like [Mark Tool Basic](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/mark-tool-basic/id1412396724?l=en&mt=12)?

[image]

Comment: That application you linked to is free. Any reason why you can't use that?

Comment: @Joonas I'm using that right now, but I am curious if Pixelmator Pro has that feature.

Comment: I see. I don't think it has. They only mention a ruler in their website. I don't know if it has plugins, but those could possibly add that functionality. — What's the use case? If I handle the coding, I tend to use [PixelSnap](https://getpixelsnap.com/) (check the video). I find it better, that I can take measurements on demand, rather than have them all sit there. By the way, it takes measurements anywhere from the screen. You don't have to take screenshots or open files. For colors I use [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/) or [Sip](https://sipapp.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Pixelmator has a ruler, but I am at this time unaware of a native-to-Pixelmator method to turn that ruler into persistent dimensions à la CAD.

I use the old but still working **Xscope** for this kind of thing myself, though both **Mark Tool** and **PixelSnap** are effective, I also use **PageLayers** for web capture to separate layers of complex designs, and though it's depreciated, I love **Layers** on Mac OS for screencaps - you get a fully layered PSD with each rendered UI element on a separate layer.

Hope that helps.